# Replace string using scala - Gatling

Tags: string, scala, replace, gatling

I want to replace orderUri /order/cart/ with /base-order/page/orders/ using scala.

orderUri -> https://order.com/dev/order/cart/5000-2429

`orderUri.replaceAll("/order/cart/", "/base-order/page/orders/")` --> This is not replacing the string, it just gives the original orderUri as it is.

Expected output:  https://order.com/dev/base-order/page/orders/5000-2429

**Updated it with the scala gatling code and it did not replace with the modified url.**

This is scala Gatling code.

```
private val orderUri = "https://order.com/dev/order/cart/5000-2429"
private val overrideUri = orderUri.replaceAll("/order/cart/", "/base-order/page/orders/")
    
    
        def run: ChainBuilder =
            pause(pauseBy(5) seconds)
              .exec(postAuction(s"${overrideUri}/base-orders/training", s"#{}", 200, s"order for #{$Year}")
                .check(jsonPath(skipNewHireStatus).is("done")))
```

here in the above code snippet, the url is still https://order.com/dev/order/cart/5000-2429/base-orders/training

instead of https://order.com/dev/base-order/page/orders/5000-2429/base-orders/training

Answer (score 4):

`replaceAll` does not modify the string, it returns a new one with applied replacement:

```scala
val orderUri = "https://order.com/dev/order/cart/5000-2429"
val neworderUri = orderUri.replaceAll("/order/cart/", "/base-order/page/orders/")
println(orderUri) // https://order.com/dev/order/cart/5000-2429
println(neworderUri) // https://order.com/dev/base-order/page/orders/5000-2429
```

Comment: I updated the post above, yes, i tried already the exact same way you mentioned here in the gatling test written in scala above, and the modified url is not used for the POST call. Can you please check the code above?

Comment: @Banu - was not able to repro [@scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/84gbt2XYSlaZEWa9lTI2BQ)